# Golang exec.Command error on Windows due to double quote

Tags: windows, go, cmd, exe, double-quotes

I have this comment, which downloads a simple file:

```
var tarMode = "xf"
cmdEnsure = *exec.Command("cmd", "/C", fmt.Sprintf(`curl -L -o file.zip "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=theIDofthefile" && tar -%s file.zip`, tarMode))
err := cmdEnsure.Run()
```

This code in go will error because:
`curl: (1) Protocol ""https" not supported or disabled in libcurl`.

Now I understand that this happends due to my double quote. However, if I remove if, I get the `Id is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`, which makes sense because the `&` simple means doing another command in `cmd`.

So what are my options for executing such download command and extract.
The command itself run fine on `cmd`.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `&` by preceding it with `^`?

Comment: There is no reason to use an external curl or tar invocation to download and untar a file. Just do it in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it best to not try and combine multiple commands in one execution. The below works just fine and you don't have to worry about escaping and portability, you also get better error handling.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    if b, err := exec.Command("curl", "-L", "-o", "file.zip", "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=theIDofthefile").CombinedOutput(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v, %v", string(b), err)
        return
    }

    if b, err := exec.Command("tar", "-x", "-f", "file.zip").CombinedOutput(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v, %v", string(b), err)
    }
}
```